# Avoid Jest reporting coverage from unchanged files which are referred in other test while using ChanedSince

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

How can i avoid Jest reporting coverage from unchanged files which are referred in other test.

I am using jest --coverage --changedsince.

Eg:- I have changes in file 1.ts, my 1.test.ts refers to 2.ts. My coverage report includes both 1.ts as well 2.ts. Also, the coverage is indicated only by the lines coverage through 1.test.ts and not 2.test.ts

Comment: `flags` with `search file pattern` and it will run only that files match pattern

Comment: @AshishKamble Cant do this. I am using in conjuction with coveragethresold, so i will need coverage from only changed files and not other files.